# customize error message 'please fill out this form' in Django

Tags: django

I have written this function in Django to override the 'label suffix and form field error message. Within the same function, the lebel suffix is working (the colon is removed) but the error message did not replaced by with customized one. 
Here is the form class with the function:

```
class User_accountModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # to remove colons from the labels:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(User_accountModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # changing error messages:
        for field in self.fields.values():
        field.error_messages = {'required':'The field {fieldname} is required'.format(fieldname=field.label)}



    class Meta:
        model = User_account
        fields = ['first_name', 'other fields']
```

any help or clue is appreciated

Comment: Just a hint: Is the form actually being posted (a request being sent) ? Maybe you are seeing the browsers own error message that a certain field is required.

Comment: actually, I am not asking about the error. I want just to customized the error message for message different from the one built in Django

Comment: Ok, see my answer for a pointer

Answer (score 1):

To override the forms error messages, add it to the forms `Meta`; see also the [`ModelForm` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields):

```
class User_accountModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User_account
        fields = ['first_name', 'other fields']
        error_messages = {
            'first_name': {
                # for example:
                'max_length': _("This writer's name is too long."),
            },
        }
```